# Why are there different TEXT like macros for the same thing in win32?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I want to know the reason why there are macros such as T, TEXT, _TEXT, __TEXT or __T when they all ultimately do the same thing.

i.e.

mapping "string" to L"string" if UNICODE is defined.

Thanks for the answers. On a more practical approach, can somebody explain me the behavior of the code given below?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <tchar.h>   // For _T and _TEXT
#include <windows.h> // For __TEXT 

int __cdecl main ()

{

  printf ("%s", _TEXT(__FILE__ ));  // Works fine

  printf ("%s", _T(__FILE__));      // Works fine

  printf ("%s", __TEXT(__FILE__ )); // error C2065: 'L__FILE__': undeclared identifier

  _getwch();

}
```

Update:
I think my code has something to do with C preprocessor tokenization. I am posting a separate question for that. Thanks.

Comment: Because we're Microsoft, and that's how we roll.

Comment: Thankfully, nowadays we can happily forget all about ANSI and just write `L"Hello world!"`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As it is often the case with "arcane" things, Raymond Chen [gives some information](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040212-00/?p=40643) (emphasis added):

> So what's with all these different ways of saying the same thing?
> There's actually a method behind the madness.
>
> The plain versions **without the underscore affect the character set the
> Windows header files treat as default**. So if you define `UNICODE`, then
> `GetWindowText` will map to `GetWindowTextW` instead of `GetWindowTextA`,
> for example. Similarly, the `TEXT` macro will map to `L"..."` instead of
> `"..."`.
>
> The versions **with the underscore affect the character set the
> C runtime header files treat as default**. So if you define `_UNICODE`,
> then `_tcslen` will map to `wcslen` instead of `strlen`, for example.
> Similarly, the `_TEXT` macro will map to `L"..."` instead of `"..."`.   What
> about `_T`? Okay, I don't know about that one. Maybe it was just to save
> somebody some typing.

Comment: What about `__TEXT` and `__T`?

Comment: @KerrekSB I have no idea (hence the quote of Raymond's site; not my words/wisdom). Maybe you could drop him a question in the "suggestion box"; but I guess the queue/wait is rather long ;-)

Comment: @KerrekSB: the trick with TEXT-like macros is that they need to be done in two steps: you can't just do `#define TEXT(str) L ## str`  - as this won't work with `__FILE__` or other string macros - you just get `L__FILE__` - which is what the OP is seeing. Instead you have to do it in two steps with a helper macro - and `__TEXT` is that helper. You end up with: `#define TEXT(str) __TEXT(str)` - and - `#define __TEXT(str) L ## str`.  Now by the time that `__TEXT` is used, `__FILE__` has been expanded into a string, so L gets prepended to that properly. (Search for TEXT in winnt.h for details.)

Answer (score 5):

For many macros, there is the Win32 one and the one for the C run-time library.  That would explain TEXT (Win32) and _TEXT (C run-time library).  The double-underscore versions are probably helper macros not intended for general use.  The T is probably a convenience for those who think TEXT is too long.

Answer (score 4):

The `UNICODE` symbol affects the declarations in Windows API headers (primarily `<windows.h>`), while the `_UNICODE` and `_MBCS` symbols affect the declarations in the C library.

Windows API example: with `UNICODE` defined `MessageBox` maps to `MessageBoxW`, in Windows terminology the *Unicode version*, while with `UNICODE` undefined `MessageBox` maps to `MessageBoxA`, the *ANSI version*.

A C library example is more involved.

In spite of two symbols `_UNICODE` and `_MBCS` there are just three cases that are distinguished:

- None of them defined, and e.g. `_tcslen` maps to `strlen`, the *narrow character version*.
- `_MBCS` defined and `_UNICODE` not defined, and e.g. `_tcsclen` maps to `_mbslen`, the *multi-byte character version*.
- `_UNICODE` defined and `_MBCS` not defined, and e.g. `_tcslen` maps to `wcslen`, the *wide character version*.

It's worth noting that all this stuff was in support of Windows 9x, which did not have a wide character API.

However, in 2001 Microsoft introduced the **Layer for Unicode**, which essentially provided a wide character API for Windows 9x. And with that, the whole scheme above was obsoleted except for one case, that of using MFC as DLLs in Windows 9x, and being unable or unwilling to rebuild it. Well, also except that whoever maintains Visual Studio's code generation has, as of version 11, not yet caught on to that fact of ten years ago, and that this in turn misleads hordes of newbies, who then as professionals are seriously unwilling to stop using this non-productive time wasting scheme.

Answer (score 0):

To provide (backward) compatibility and to be compatible with code written for other platforms

Comment: Compatibility with code written for other platforms has never been high on MS's priority list.

Comment: Details, please. Backward compatibility to *what*, exactly? What other platforms does code written with all those macros provide compatibility with?

Comment: Backward compatibility with Windows 95 and other platforms which don't support the UTF16 character encoding of unicode.