# DirectX 9 window doesnt show

Tags: c++, directx-9

I am trying to make a simple DirectX 9 program that creates a windowed mode window and shows it (nothing will be drawn to the window yet). When I compile the program, I get no errors. When I run the program, the window doesn't show and the program terminates.

```
/*
* A simple DirectX 9 program to create a windowed mode window with nothing drawn on it. No errors when compiled or ran, but no window  * pops up and program terminates almost immediately.
*/

#include <Windows.h>
#include <d3d9.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//program settings
const string APPTITLE = "Direct3D_Windowed";
const int SCREENW = 1024;
const int SCREENH = 768;


//Direct3D object
LPDIRECT3D9 d3d = NULL;
LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 d3ddev = NULL;

bool gameOver = false;

//macro to detect key presses
#define KEY_DOWN(vk_code)((GetAsyncKeyState(vk_code) & 0x8000) ? 1:0)

/*
* Game initialization function
*/
bool Game_Init(HWND window)
{

    //init Direct3D
    d3d = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);
    if (d3d == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    //set Direct3D presentation parameters
    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;
    ZeroMemory(&d3dpp, sizeof(d3dpp));
    d3dpp.Windowed = TRUE;
    d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
    d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8;
    d3dpp.BackBufferCount = 1;

    d3dpp.BackBufferWidth = SCREENW;
    d3dpp.BackBufferHeight = SCREENH;
    d3dpp.hDeviceWindow = window;

    //create Direct3D device
    d3d->CreateDevice(
        D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,
        D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,
        window,
        D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING,
        &d3dpp,
        &d3ddev);

    if (d3ddev == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    return true;
}

/*
* Game update function
*/
void Game_Run(HWND hwnd)
{
    //make sure the Direct3D device is valid
    if (!d3ddev)
    {
        return;
    }

    //clear the backbuffer to bright green
    d3ddev->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 255, 0), 1.0f, 0);

    //start rendering
    if (d3ddev->BeginScene())
    {
        //do something?

        //stop rendering
        d3ddev->EndScene();

        //copy back buffer on the screen
        d3ddev->Present(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    }

    //check for escape key (to exit program)
    if (KEY_DOWN(VK_ESCAPE))
    {
        PostMessage(hwnd, WM_DESTROY, 0, 0);
    }
}

/*
* Game shutdown function
*/
void Game_End(HWND hwnd)
{

    //free the memory
    if (d3ddev)
    {
        d3ddev->Release();
    }
    if (d3d)
    {
        d3d->Release();
    }
}

/*
* Windows event handling function
*/
LRESULT WINAPI WinProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        gameOver = true;
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

/*
* Main Windows entry function
*/
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    //set the new window's properties
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)WinProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = NULL;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH);
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = APPTITLE.c_str();
    wc.hIconSm = NULL;
    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    //create a new window
        HWND window = CreateWindow(
        APPTITLE.c_str(),       //window class
        APPTITLE.c_str(),       //title bar
        //fullscreen mode
        //WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_VISIBLE | WS_POPUP,
        //windowed mode 
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,    //window style
        CW_USEDEFAULT,          //x position of window
        CW_USEDEFAULT,          //y position of window
        640,                    //width of the window
        480,                    //height of the window
        NULL,                   //parent window
        NULL,                   //menu
        hInstance,              //appkication instance
        NULL);                  //window parameters


    //was there an error creating the window?
    if (window == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    //display the window
    ShowWindow(window, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(window);

    //initialize the game
    if (!Game_Init(window))
    {
        return 0;
    }

    //main message loop
    MSG message;
    while (!gameOver)
    {
        if (PeekMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&message);
            DispatchMessage(&message);
        }
        Game_Run(window);
    }

    Game_End(window);

    return message.wParam;
}
```

Comment: First of all, how do you know why the program terminated? You just return 0 if *anything* goes wrong. That's not useful for finding out what went wrong (although you could use a debugger). Secondly, you never check whether `RegisterClassEx` is successful. Thirdly, use the wide string versions of the winapi functions. Along those lines, http://i.imgur.com/IMZe6OU.png

Comment: Actually, wait, that last one was me missing a function when adding A to the end of things to make it compile without going and changing my definitions. While I'm taking another comment, the globals are unnecessary, `gameOver` is unnecessary, `KEY_DOWN` should be a function, and `WndProc` shouldn't be casted (if it doesn't compile, it's not right).

Comment: Honestly I'm following along with a book "Beginning Game Programming Third Edition by Jonathan S. Harbour". In his example he has several function calls such as "MessageBox(window, "Game_Init", "BREAKPOINT", 0);" (this function is inside the Game_Init() function. But I have to remove or comment these out because they cause an error.

Comment: It's ok to follow along with a book (FWIW, I've heard good things about Frank Luna's), but every DX book I've seen uses terrible C++ practices. That's reasonable considering the focus is on DX, but it really sucks if you don't know much C++.

Comment: Yeah I know these are not good programming practices, and i've taken 2 c++ classes in college, but no experience with DX. And I'm sure what you mean by using the wide string versions of the winapi functions.

Comment: Use `-DUNICODE` or whatever applies to your compiler and pass wide strings to the functions. Let's say you wanted to change the title to Japanese without any hassle. Given the program's current state, 一二三四五 appears to me as http://i.imgur.com/Lo6PVUs.png. Winapi functions that take strings generally have an A version and a W version and which is called is based on that definition being present. New applications should use the wide versions so more than 250 or so characters will work properly.

Comment: Alright, well I wouldn't think that would cause the program to not show the window. Which is all im pretty much going for at the moment (I will work on better programming practices and get it to work with Unicode).

Comment: It wouldn't. *Secondly, you never check whether RegisterClassEx is successful.*

Answer (score 0):

When you set the window's properties, you need to set the cbSize member.

```
wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
```

Comment: The APPTITLE error is because you need to change the settings from Unicode to Multi-byte. I will try the cbSize that you suggested.

Comment: Use `L` instead of `TEXT`, especially when you're initializing a wide string with that data.

Comment: Glad it worked! Yeah I kinda realized afterwards, but I'm too lazy.. haha

@chris [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314552/why-are-there-different-text-like-macros-for-the-same-thing-in-win32) makes me think that depending on whether Unicode is supported or not, TEXT can either map to L"..." or "...", but if I only use L".." only, it might cause problems for systems that don't support Unicode..

Comment: @Salads, By systems that don't support Unicode, I hope you know that you're talking about versions of Windows that start at almost 20 years old.

Comment: @Salads, The benefits of not using `TCHAR` and bringing in all of its associated problems (no `std::tstring`, even with a type alias, no `std::stoi` or `std::to_string` for it, no other character-based things that support it, `TEXT` calls everywhere, two separate builds on top of any other build splits) greatly outweigh supporting versions of Windows that only specific applications have a need to support.

Comment: FWIW, all ASCII versions of Win32 APIs are deprecated for Windows Store apps, Windows phone 8.x, and Xbox One. UNICODE only is the way to go. You'd have to go back to Windows 95 to find a version of Windows without UNICODE support.

Comment: Well, I guess I'm reading an outdated book on Win32 since it's talking about Windows NT and what not..