# TEXT macro causing error in Intellisense VSCode

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-code

I am learning how to use `<windows.h>` to create console applications. However, I ran across this strange error on VS Code(minimum reproducable code):

```cpp
#include <windows.h>

int main(){
    const char * c = "Hello";
    TEXT("Hello");      // No error. L"Hello" is a literal
    TEXT(c);            // Error: "identifier "Lc" is undefined"
    return 0;
}
```

I also looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314552/why-are-there-different-text-like-macros-for-the-same-thing-in-win32), but there is no answer as to *why* this particular error occurs
*(presumably also on Code?)* and just differentiates between the different macros.
I know `TEXT(Q)` expands to `__TEXT(Q)` which further generates `L##Q`.
It compiles alright, but VS Code Intellisense still marks this an error.

**My problem is**: *Why is this showing an error in VS Code?*

It is not exactly an issue, but it doesn't look nice on the screen.
For the screenshot, see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/82923

Comment: Are you sure it compiles? I doubt it does.

Comment: It does: `g++ big.cpp -o big.exe`. Should I attach a screenshot?

Comment: No, I figured it out. See the answer below.

Comment: Downvoter please enlighten me for the downvote?

Comment: What do you want to do with `Text(c);`, `c` is not a literal string so undefined behavior if you use it with this macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TEXT("foo")` can expand either to `L"foo"` or `"foo"`, depending on whether `UNICODE` macro is defined or not.

Apparently VSCode intellisense assumes it's defined, but GCC doesn't define it by default.

If it's not defined, `TEXT(c);` expands to `c;`, and since there's a variable called `c`, you don't get a complation error.

To prevent GCC from disagreeing with the intellisense, you can `-DUNICODE` flag to the GCC invocation (or somehow tell intellisense to not define this macro).

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer. However, the solution is not working. See [my continuation post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58474777/text-macro-causing-error-in-intellisense-vscode-continued).